# VB Array IndexOf error (Noughts and Crosses Game)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Being new to programming and having it introduced to me through my course I've been doing tasks in and out of College in Visual Basic using Visual Studio to make games and other little applications. However in my most recent project i've experienced a problem in one of my arrays I have never come across before. The specific error im getting comes up with this when highlighted:

> Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Shared Overloads Function IndexOf(Of T)(array As T(), value As T) As Integer' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

I have all the arrays (18, for 9 different buttons each containing a question and an answer variant) running in form load as it was the only way I could get the arrays to work with a randomiser and show the question in the button. Then the array index is being found and created in the submit answer button. I'll give some snippets for further context below from various points where the array is being referenced :)

I created this to make the string global but I have an inkling this is wrong?

```
Public Class Form3
Public QBox1 As String
Public QBoxA1 As String
```

This is where the arrays are and how i've structured them

```
Public Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
BOX 1 (TOP LEFT)
Dim QBox1() As String = {"√81", "4x6", "16/4", "21+18", "81-23"}
Dim QBoxA1() As Integer = {"9", "24", "4", "39", "58"}
```

And finally this is within the submit answer button where the error is

```
If QBoxA1.Contains(txt_AnswerAttempt.Text) Then

Dim question_index = Array.IndexOf(QBox1, btn_Q1.Text)
Dim answer_index = Array.IndexOf(QBoxA1, answerAttemptDisplay.Text)

If question_index = answer_index Then
MsgBox("Correct Answer!")

Else
MsgBox("Wrong Answer!")

End If

End If
```

Sorry for information overload, I wanted to be thorough right off the bat! Cheers for giving this a read if you made it to the end xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration isn't right.  Since you want an array, don't declare it as a single string.  It should be:

```
Public QBox1() As String
```

then in the load event, don't re-declare it with a Dim statement.  Just re-populate it:

```
QBox1 = {"√81", "4x6", "16/4", "21+18", "81-23"}
```

Comment: Cheers for the help bud, i'm assuming the explanation for the problem is something along the lines of the variable is being set as a string too many times causing some sort of overload in the program?

Comment: @KingZ The original declaration was just a string that was null.  By using `Dim` inside a method block, you declared your array, but that declaration was only scoped inside the loading event — it didn't exist outside of it.